# Restore page and state on browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, server-side-rendering, next.js

**Description**

I'm using React.js with server side rendering using Next.js framework 
I have "Search" page, which state is initialized using getInitialProps (loads data from API server), and "Object" page. 
User can navigate from Search page to Object page, using simple `<a>` tag. 
On search page user can filter data, each filter do new API request and recieve new data.

**The problem**

After filtering on Search page, user click on item and goes to Object page. Then user clicks browser Back button.

*What is now* - I got the same search page which was on first load without filtering. Can anybody explain how it is restored and what exactly is restoring?

*What I need* - I need restore html and state which was after filtering.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should use `localStorage()`, and store every filter in it. When loading your Search Page, apply those filters from the `localStorage`.

Comment: @VictorBaron , I have no client side filtering, I receive filtered data from api. I tried to save data and filters in local storage, but I can apply it too late, browser renders old data, and then rerenders new (from localstorage). I need something witout this blinking

Comment: Where do you apply your data in `localStorage`? IMHO that should be done in `componentWillMount`

Comment: @VictorBaron just tried with `componentWillMount` , I still see old data and after milliseconds data from `localStorage`

Comment: Render method called once with right data, but it looks like browser restores page from another source without calling Render

Comment: I might need further information of your code to help you there.

Comment: @VictorBaron will try to make some public code example with same logic and share link here

Comment: @VictorBaron so that problem was solved using GET parameters. but receive another problem, with back button, maybe it is connected with it too. I created an issue here - https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1953 - there is a link to my test repository. Maybe I have some misunderstanding about how to work with history and redux state and next.js